# Azure Cosmos DB with SpringBoot Java - Paginate by page number and size

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is there a better way to paginate by page number and size? I'm going through the below [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmosdb-springboot-pagination/blob/a53f69a8f4fcae296d4a8952bb2754b12902e4a9/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/cosmosdb/pagination/volcano/service/VolcanoService.java#L21),

```
public List<Volcano> getAllVolcanoesByPage(Integer pageNo, Integer pageSize, String sortBy) {
        final Pageable pageable = new CosmosPageRequest(0, pageSize, null);
        List<Volcano> content = null;

        Page<Volcano> page = this.repository.findAll(pageable);
        if (pageNo == 0) {
            content = page.getContent();
            for (Volcano volcano : content) System.out.println(volcano.toString());
            return content;
        } else {
            Page<Volcano> nextPage = null;
            for (int i = 1; i <= pageNo; i++) {
                nextPage = this.repository.findAll(page.getPageable());
                /* reset page to nextpage like a linkedlist*/
                page = nextPage;
                content = nextPage.getContent();
                for (Volcano volcano : content) System.out.println(volcano.toString());
            }
            return content;
        }
    }
```

The above implementation iterates every page until the requested number, and this impacts the performance when the number and size increases.
I know we can get the next set of records using `continuationToken` but is there a better way with page number and size?

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/how-to-guides-spring-data-cosmosdb

```
@Query("select * from c offset @offset limit @limit")
```

You might need to calculate the offset and limit but after that this may work.